# What is the difference between the glycolate pathway and photorespiration?

Tags: plant-physiology

I came across the definition of photorespiration as a process that forms CO2 from O2 in the presence of light. However, the CO2 is released only when the plant cell undergoes the conversion of glycolate to PGA, i.e in the glycolate pathway.

Most textbooks seem to use the term photorespiration and glycolate pathway interchangeably, but then they seem to say that the glycolate pathway evolved to regain the energy lost in the formation of glycolate, whereas photorespiration is wasteful. How is this possible?

Shouldn't photorespiration be a conservation pathway as well? It is trying to regain lost energy from glycolate, isn't it? or Have I got the two terms completely confused?

Please Explain

Comment: I don't even think that photorespiration is wasteful. It seems to me like plants generate CO2 for photosynthesis when amount of CO2 in environment is less.

Comment: Can you actually describe what process according to you is photorespiration?

Comment: As per what I have studied, I can define photorespiration as the process in which RuBisCO uses O2 and produces CO2 when amount of Oxygen in environment is higher than that of CO2. But, though it uses more ATP and also produces ammonia,  it seems to me like plant is generating CO2 for its own benifit i.e. photosynthesis. So it does not seem totally wasteful.

Comment: That would actually make some sense as the feedback for that would be less photorespiration and more photsynthesis due to increase in CO2 concentration. So in those terms glycolate pathway is just a pathway for photorespiration, right?

Comment: From http://plantsinaction.science.uq.edu.au/book/export/html/64 "Wang and Waygood (1962) had described the ‘glycolate pathway’, namely a series of reactions in which glycolate is oxidised to glyoxylate and aminated, first to form glycine and subsequently the three-carbon amino acid serine." So, it says that glycolate pathway is just a part of photorespiration in which glycolate is metabolized.

Comment: I appreciate the attraction of the idea that Nature is too smart to allow wasteful processes, but the suggestion made by @another 'Homo sapiens' just won't wash. I know of no evidence that the concentration of CO2 in the atmosphere varies appreciably, and if it did I can't see that the production of CO2 by plants would affect it significantly. And I imagine there have been many previous attempts to rationalize this inconvenient truth.

Comment: @David Amount of CO2 doesn't vary appreciably, but that of O2 does. Because RuBisCO cannot choose O2 instead of CO2 just because % of O2 has risen by 0.001% or something. By photorespiration, plant not only produces CO2, but also consumes O2 i.e. it increases amount of CO2 two-fold, which might affect it significantly. Also, when it comes to smartness of nature, there can be a long debate about why evolution gave rise to photorespiration and why plants still use C3 cycle.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to the question posed in the title of the question is as follows. The glycolate pathway is the series of reactions converting phosphogycolate to reusable carbon intermediates + CO2. Photorespiration is the combination of two processes:

1. The oxidation of the enodiolate intermediate on Rubisco to phosphoglycoate + 3-phosphoglycerate.
2. The processing of the phosphoglycolate produced by the glycolate pathway.

You cannot use the two interchangeably as there is no respiration (use of oxygen) in the glycolate pathway. The glycolate pathway is just the latter part of photorespiration. I'm not sure what the text books are that confuse the two, but Stryer presents this quite clearly in Figure 20.6 and 20.7 at http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22344/#A2795.

I am not familiar with the term "conservation pathway" in your final question. I would call the glycolate pathway a "salvage pathway" (although this term is more commonly used for recycling the skeletons of the products of macromolecular, esp. DNA, degradation). It does not salvage all of the carbon skeleton of phosphoglycolate as some carbon is lost to the atmosphere as CO2.